# Configure Comodo for SSH access

Tags: ssh, comodo-firewall

ALL

I have Windows 8.1 n my laptop and Comodo Firewall Free Edition.

I want to set up an SSH access to GitHub.

I already generated the keys from the Git Bash and dropped it to the github.com, but trying the `ssh -T <user>@github.co` the comand times out.

My guess is that I need to somehow configure Comodo to allow traffic on port 22 coming from my laptop.

Trying to google, I see a links to the Comodo set up SSH access, but I think those links are about the paid version of Comodo, as no such screens exists in my version.

So how do I configure Comodo Free Edition Firewall to allow SSH traffic on port 22?

TIA!!

If it matters - I have version 12.2.2.8012 of Comodo.

Comment: I just installed the same version, and I'm able to SSH out without any problems. The configuration looks to me like "Allow out everything everywhere", which I would expect from a "consumer-grade" firewall. Of course setting up a rule "allow SSH out" doesn't hurt. But before doing that - did you make a typo on that ssh command above?

Comment: @Peregrino69, no I didn't. The github is timing out which indicates it a firewall blocking traffic. Do you know how to configure SSH access n Coodo? Or at least create a rule for port 22?

Comment: @Peregrino69, I just tried with `ssh -T git@github.com` and got the same result `Connection timed out`.

Comment: Oki. That's a different ballgame now. Just for a test - disable the firewall. Right-click tray icon -> Firewall -> Disable.

Comment: @Peregrino69, I did and got the same result. `Connection timed out`. I also tried to close the Comodo completely. What else could stop the connection?

Comment: Any diff? As for your question... I just installed Comodo, and have been looking at it for about half an hour or so. It looks pretty simple, and as far as I can see, in default configuration all egress traffic is allowed. So far I've figured out how to block and allow all kinds of traffic - what I've *not* managed to do is create a rule to *block* outgoing SSH...

Comment: Let's respect the rules and move this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129336/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-igor).

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this issue - I was able to connect to git service over HTTPS (port 443). My router is set up to use Maximum Security Firewall and so I think port 22 is locked for both in and out traffic.